# Sonar rules definition XML format

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

Where can I find a good documentation and/or schema for the XML file used to import rules to Sonar?
There is some documentation on http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/5.1/apidocs/org/sonar/api/server/rule/RulesDefinitionXmlLoader.html, but it is not accurate (e.g. description is marked optional, but Sonar fails if it is missing) and there is no description what each element represents.

I am using Sonar 5.2 RC2, but format probably did not change from the previous versions.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I need to import to SonarQube rules from another application and want to understand what each XML element represents and what are the constraints. For example I am pretty sure key should be unique, but have doubts about the name element. Purpose of other XML elements is also not completely clear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find some documentation but you can have a look at an example that is up to date: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-findbugs/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/sonar/plugins/findbugs/rules.xml

Comment: The example is giving some insights, but it is not complete and I am not sure how up to date it is. For example according to SonarQube code specifying "key"as attribute is deprecated and a separate XML element should be used instead.

Comment: The attribute "key" is indeed deprecated and replaced by the element with same name. Except the fact the the description is required, the javadoc of RulesDefinitionXmlLoader is up-to-date. Comments will be added to 5.2-GA though.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to import rules from some other tool simply with an XML file. Instead, you'll need to write a full plugin, and the one David RACODON cited is a good example: the [SonarQube FindBugs plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-findbugs).

Comment: That's what I am writing. Just wanted to understand format of the XML better